# I have 1 form with 2 submit buttons

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to set-up a form that has 2 buttons, accept and deny. It doesn't seem to be working. Any thoughts on what I should fix?

```
   <form name="iform" method="post" onsubmit="" onreset="" enctype="multipart/form-data"    action="formapprovedeny" class="iform">
```

Form content here.

```
   <input type="button" onclick="submitForm('html_form_approve.php')"      class="submit_button" value="Approved" name="Approved" />
   <input type="button" class="submit_button" onclick="submitForm('html_form_deny.php')" value="Denied" name="Denied" />


   </form>
```

Here is the script part.

```
     <script>
function submitForm(action)
{
    document.getElementById('formapprovedeny').action = action;
    document.getElementById('formapprovedeny').submit();
}
  </script>
```

Comment: Can you specify 'not working'? Doesn't it work on either page? Do you receive calls on the server? Any logging in the browser console?

Comment: Your for does not have id "formapprovedeny"

Comment: Your form doesn't have an `id="formapprovedeny"`

Comment: You could also check on the server side which button was pressed and handle it from there.

Comment: missing id...Thanks everyone. I needed an extra pair of eyes.

Comment: How about using `formaction` on the input instead?

Answer (score 3):

Your Javscript is trying to submit a form with an `id` of `formapprovedeny` but your form does not have an `id`. Try adding `id="formapprovedeny"` to your form

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your naming.

You try to get the `form` by it's `id`, but it is not set. It's `name` is.

You should use either `getElementByName` or give your form an `id`.

Answer (score 0):

It should  `id="formapprovedeny"` not `action="formapprovedeny"`

```
<form name="iform" method="post" onsubmit="" onreset="" enctype="multipart/form-data"    id="formapprovedeny" class="iform">
```

Answer (score -1):

The type of button must be 'submit' and the value whatever you want, look this:

```
<input type="submit" class="submit_button" value="Approved" name="Approved" />
<input type="submit" class="submit_button" value="Denied" name="Denied" />
```

Comment: OP has a JS function that does the submit.

Answer (score -1):

What do you want to achieve using the 2 buttons? What do you expect?
http://jsfiddle.net/xaW5P/

```
<script>
function submitForm(action)
{
    alert('hello submitForm '+action);
    document.getElementById('formapprovedeny').action = action;
    document.getElementById('formapprovedeny').submit();
}
  </script>
```

if I use your code (added an alert) this seems to work...whatever it should be doing ;)

Comment: OP has 2 buttons, with 2 different behaviours. So the click on the button should change the `action` attribute.

Comment: works in jsfiddle
> hello submitForm html_form_approve.php
> hello submitForm html_form_deny.php

Comment: No, it doesn't since the problem is in finding the element with the specified id, not in showing an alert.